# Excel VBA For loop with variable index not working

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

My data set looks like this

```
Name    ID

Alice   1

Alice   2

Alice   -4

Bob    4

Bob    7

2344   9

2344   10

4I    99

4I   04
```

What I want it to look like is this:

```
Name    ID

Alice   1

Alice   2

Alice   -4



Name    ID

Bob    4

Bob    7




Name    ID

2344   9

2344   10



Name    ID

4I    99

4I   04
```

Every time the name entry changes, I want to introduce 1 empty rows and a row of my header.

```
    Sub insertingrows()


  FinalColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  For j = 3 To FinalRow

    If Cells(j, 2) <> Cells(j - 1, 2) Then
        'Rows(j & ":" & j + 2).Insert
        Rows(j).Insert
        Rows(1).Copy
        Rows(j + 1).Insert
        FinalRow = FinalRow + 2
        j = j + 2
    End If

  Next j



End Sub
```

My initial actual data has 3830 rows  but even though I am updating my variable FinalRow inside the loop, the loop is still stopping around 3830 and is leaving a lot of the process unfinished. Is this a limitation of For? Should I use some other type of loop?

Comment: Will the data be always sorted?

Comment: No, but I'll just add a sort command before hand in the VBA script.

Comment: You have to use a reverse loop

Comment: @SiddharthRout What is a reverse loop?

Comment: I was about to post the answer but since @rdhs has already done it, I will pass on this one :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout This is a bit bizarre but for the last 50 minutes, I have tried to run rdhs's script about 5 times and everytime my excel has crashed. But when I run my old script it runs fine. Any guesses?

Comment: LOL, I discarded my script... do you want me post an answer? I can re-write it?

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes please. I'd appreciate it. I cannot understand why my system keeps crashing with rdhs's script.

Comment: The data is in which column?

Comment: @SiddharthRout In my stackoverflow example, the relevant column is column 1 but in my real life data, the relevant column with the IDs is column 2.

Comment: Are you still facing problems with the code that I gave below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your worksheet looks like this

[image]

Put this code in a module

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = lRow To 3 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value <> .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
                .Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                .Cells(i, 1).Value = "Name": .Cells(i, 2).Value = "ID"
                .Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The bounds of a `For` loop are calculated once, when the loop begins, and then become flat numbers. If you want to change the bounds, fall back to a `Do` loop:

```
j = 3
Do

    If Cells(j, 2) <> Cells(j - 1, 2) Then
        'Rows(j & ":" & j + 2).Insert
        Rows(j).Insert
        Rows(1).Copy
        Rows(j + 1).Insert
        FinalRow = FinalRow + 2
        j = j + 3
    End If

Loop While j < FinalRow
```

Comment: cool thanks! Great to know that Do accommodates change of bounds.

Comment: As I wrote in the comments above, for the last 50 minutes, I have tried to run your script about 5 times and every time my excel has crashed, just frozen and not responding. But when I run my old script it runs fine (although it stops at row 3830). Any guesses?

Comment: When you increment `j` in the loop, are you doing it as `j = j + 3` as I have, or `j = j + 2` like in your code for the `For` loop?

Comment: I did j=j+3 like you changed it since While does not have the increment of Next j.